# Replace matching elements including nested ones

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace all occurences of `span` having `id="comment_n"`, where `n` can be any number and any occurence of this qualifying `span` can have nested ones. Each `span` can have different attributes. Example:

```
foo <span id="comment_1">text <span id="comment_2" attr="value">text.</span></span> bar
```

I have this regular expression:

```
<span id="comment_\d+.+?<\/span>
```

But it doesn't include the last closing `span` tag.

I need to do a replace:

```
Regex.Replace(input, regex, string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Demo: http://regexr.com/3bpkf

Comment: This is really very fragile. You are testing a .NET regex on a JavaScript regex engine for parsing HTML. Perhaps, XPath `//span[starts-with(@id, 'comment_')]` is sufficient, if not, you can later check if the `id` attribute value contains a digit after `comment_` with just string/char methods.

Comment: It would be educative to be learn about the reason for the downvote, just to improve my next question.

Comment: I think the only reason is that you try to manipulate HTML structure with regex. There is a strong "anti-regex lobby" on SO. The question itself is quite well written and clear, only you do not specify what you final outcome should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using HtmlAgilityPack to obtain what you need. You can specify the XPath to only get the `<span>` tags having `id` attribute that starts with `comment_` (case-insensitive) and then remove them. Additional check for the number after `comment_` can be done with a regex, or without. Here is a way to remove some tags having specific attribute value where this value is checked with a regex.

```
public string HtmlAgilityPackRemoveTagsWithSpecificAttribute(string html, string xpath, string attribute_name, Regex rx)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hap;
    Uri uriResult;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(html, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) &&
                              uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
    { // html is a URL 
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        hap = doc.Load(uriResult.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    else
    { // html is a string
        hap = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        hap.LoadHtml(html);
    }
    var nodes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
    if (nodes != null)
    {
       foreach (var node in nodes)
       {
           if (rx.IsMatch(node.Attributes[attribute_name].Value))
               node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
       }
    }
    return hap.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var res = HtmlAgilityPackRemoveTagsWithSpecificAttribute(html,
  "//span[starts-with(translate(@id, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
           'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'comment_')]", "id", 
                new Regex("(?i)^comment_[0-9]+$"));
```

Note that `translate` is used to enable case-insensitive comparison (`comment_`, `COMMENT_`, etc.).  If you do not need that, just use `starts-with(@id, 'comment_')]"`.

The regex can be instantiated before passing to the method if you use it more than once, or use a static `Regex.IsMatch` and replace the method signature.

Comment: Very good approach, thank you. But for nodes containing _only_ a matching span element, `node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node)` oddly removes also the closing tag of the parent element. Try this input: `<P><SPAN id=comment_1>text</SPAN></P>`. Resulting string is: `"<p>"`. A bug in HtmlAgilityPack? I'm using v1.4.9.

Comment: I mean the resulting string for input `<P><SPAN id=comment_1>text</SPAN></P>` would be `<P></P>`.

Comment: The bug seems to be already logged: [*Incorrect processing `<p>` node*](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/43167). Looks like you need to be careful with `<p>` tags being the only nodes in the HTML document. Check with `hap.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` is equal to `<p>`, and if yes, change to `<p/>` or `<p></p>` manually. :(

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

As to *why* it doesn't include the last closing `span` tag, it's because of the `?` in your regex pattern, that makes it "lazy" causing it to match the shortest satisfying string, if you remove that, the match will include the last 'span' tag:

```
<span id="comment_\d+.+<\/span>
```

But I'd suggest using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing your DOM and manipulating it.

Comment: No, that doesn't work if i have non-nested elements, i.e: `foo <span id="comment_1" attr="value">text</span> bar <span id="comment_2" attr="value">text</span> bar`.

Comment: @KristofferJälén: Do you expect to get `foo  bar  bar` after the processing of the string above? And `/foo  bar` after processing the original input in the question?